# How to write an array to allocate space for 5 things

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write an array to allocate space for 5 things for a program that I'm writing in Java, which I am new to, and need help.

Comment: This is a beginners task, there is plenty of material around for the basics...

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
private Object[] myObjects = new Object[5];
```

Change the type as needed.